# Mongoose Geolocation, Get products ordered by the location which is belongs to a different mongoose model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am creating a store manager app. Here user should be able to query the products using the products query. **The condition is those products should be ordered by the distance to products store.**

Eg: If the user is searching for a pencil then It should return all the products named pencil which belong to stores within 15 KM, and results should be ordered by the distance to the store.

// The Product Model

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Product name is required'
  },
  store: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Store',
    required: 'Store must be connected to the user'
  }
});
```

// The store model

```
const storeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please enter a store name'
  },
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: [{
      type: Number,
      required: 'You must supply coordinates!'
    }]
  },
});
```

this is how I querying products

```
  const products = await Product.find({
    name : args.name
    store:{
         near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 79.8612, 6.9271] },
         maxDistance: store.maxDistance,
         spherical: true
    }
  });
```

Unfortunately, It gives me the error

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
  near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 79.8612, 6.9271 ] },
  maxDistance: 15,
  spherical: true
}
```

I believe I have created indexes correctly

```
storeSchema.index({
  location: '2dsphere'
});
```